# De Rham cohomology of the pointed plane

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

i try to work out some examples for de Rham cohomology, but i have some problems: I want to figure out what $H^k(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\})$ is and want to generalize this to arbitrary finite points i left out of the plane. But first we can start with the first space i mentioned. We can work with the Mayer-Vietris sequence i thought. But there my problem start: What can i choose for the open sets $U$ and $V$. I thought: $U$ a little bit more then the upper half plane without $0$ and $V$ a little bit more then the lower half plane without zero but then $U$, $V$ and $U\cap V$ are homotopic to the space we start with. Can someone help me :) Thanks

Comment: Hint: you can take as $U$ and $V$ as the whole plane minus a half-line from the origin (taking for $U$ and $V$ two different half-lines). In this way $U\cong\mathbb{R}^2$, $V\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ and $U\cap V\cong\mathbb{R}^2\coprod\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: FYI: $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is called a _punctured plane_. A _pointed plane_ would be an ordered pair like $(\mathbb R^2,p)$ -- a plane together with a chosen point in that plane.

Comment: Okay i got it. Therefore i get the Mayer Vietoris sequence $0\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}\rightarrow H^1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\})\rightarrow 0$. How can i conclude what $H^1$ has to be?

Comment: Oh yes we can give an argument given by the dimensions of the spaces by exactness. Thus $\dim(H^1(\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}))=1$